# Calculating UniFrac distance

Tags: distance, bioinformatics, phylogeny

So I am trying to calculate unifrac distance for my OTU table, which has about 3000 taxa, 300 samples. Now my phylogenetic tree only consider the most important 500 taxa. My questions are:

1. Do I ignore the 2500 taxa that were not considered in the phylogenetic tree?
2. Is their a package in R that deals with this kind of missing data?

Thanks,

xD

Comment: This question is off topic.

Comment: Where should I ask it then?

Comment: @QuyXuanCao, try asking it in the [Bioinformatics Stack Exchange](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com).

Comment: awesome! Thanks!